# How to make mypy skip relative import when there is no parent package

Tags: python, static-analysis, mypy

Suppose for some ugly packaging reasons I have a file `foo.py` that contains:

```
try:
    from . import bar
except ImportError:
    import bar
```

Suppose the file structure is such that there is no `__init__.py` file so an `ImportError` is expected to be raised and caught. If I run mypy over this code, I receive the following error:

```
mypy_eg/foo.py:2: error: No parent module -- cannot perform relative import
Found 1 error in 1 file (errors prevented further checking)
```

However if I change line 2 to `from . import bar  # type: ignore`, I still get the error.

I expect this comment to skip the error. Indeed, if I try to ignore other errors in the file like this, mypy happily skips them, but just not this one for some reason.

Does anyone have any idea why this is?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the answer, since I still don't know how to disable it, but I found what causes the error. As hinted in [this issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6660), you need to have the `__init__.py` file at the top of a package tree. I created an empty one, and suddenly the import errors were gone.